# Floating point overflow and inexactness

Tags: floating-point, hardware, fpu

I found some inconsistencies in handling floating point errors on Intel hardware and I'm wondering if this is Intel hardware error or just general way of how floating point aritmetic work. Scenarios:

1) 10000 + maxfloat = 3.40282e+38
   error produced: FE_INEXACT

2) maxfloat + maxfloat = inf
   errors: FE_OVERFLOW, FE_INEXACT

3) 1.1 * maxfloat = inf
   errors: FE_OVERFLOW, FE_INEXACT

Scenario 1 is inconsisten with other two because I was exceeding float range but I did not get overflow like in case 2 and 3.

I can not comprehend why I don't get overflow and number just saturates in first case but in second and third number is not saturated and I get overflow.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>
#include <cstdio>
#include <cfenv>

void print_error() {    
    const int err = fetestexcept(FE_ALL_EXCEPT);
    if (err & FE_INVALID) cout << "FE_INVALID " << endl;            
    if (err & FE_DIVBYZERO) cout << "FE_DIVBYZERO "<< endl;
    if (err & FE_OVERFLOW) cout << "FE_OVERFLOW "<< endl;        
    if (err & FE_UNDERFLOW) cout << "FE_UNDERFLOW " << endl;
    if (err & FE_INEXACT) cout << "FE_INEXACT " << endl;
    cout << endl;      
}

int main() {
    feclearexcept(FE_ALL_EXCEPT);        
    cout << numeric_limits<float>::max() + 100000.0f << endl;
    print_error();

    feclearexcept(FE_ALL_EXCEPT);        
    cout << numeric_limits<float>::max() + numeric_limits<float>::max() << endl;
    print_error();    

    feclearexcept(FE_ALL_EXCEPT);
    cout << 1.1f*numeric_limits<float>::max() << endl;
    print_error();
}
```

Comment: 10000 + maxfloat = maxfloat. No overflow occurs.

Comment: Could it be that 10000 is so tiny compared to maxfloat that even if it could add it the result would be maxfloat?

Comment: Yes, assuming `float` maps to IEEE-754 `binary32` and rounding mode is nearest-or-even.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Scenario 1 is inconsistent with other two because I was exceeding float range but I did not get overflow like in case 2 and 3.

The sum `10000 + maxfloat` is not exactly representable, hence `FE_INEXACT`.  Instead the sum was rounded.  Rounding choices include the largest finite number `maxfloat` and the next largest finite number "as if" it could be represented with additional exponent range.  With round to nearest, the sum rounded to `maxfloat` as that is closer.

In cases 2 & 3, the sum rounded to or above this next largest finite  "as if" number.  Since the rounded sum meets/exceeds this number, infinity is returned.

---

Below is a number line showing the last 3 finite float including `FLT_MAX`.
Had float had further exponent range, the next 2 numbers after `FLT_MAX` would have been the 2 on the right: '`FLT_MAX` next "as if"' and unnamed.
"Half-way" is between `FLT_MAX` and that next largest finite  "as if" number.

When the sum is more than `FLT_MAX`, but less than "Half-way", a round-to nearest results in `FLT_MAX` (Case 1).  When the sum is greater, the result is infinity. (Case 2,3).

[image]

Comment: Very solid explanation. Could you point me to some material I can learn more about floating points?

Comment: Of course [IEEE_754](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754) and its [See also](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754#See_also) is a good start.  It really depends on where your are now.  I'll look for more specific ref about this issue.

Comment: @Trismegistos Chptr 6 of [On the definition of ulp (x)](http://ljk.imag.fr/membres/Carine.Lucas/TPScilab/JMMuller/ulp-toms.pdf) goes over some technical ideas about this issue.

Answer (score 2):

The way rounding works for finite results at the upper end of the finite range is:

- Calculate what representable number would be produced if the exponent range continued forever.
- If that result is beyond the actual range, produce infinity and report overflow and inexact. Otherwise, produce that number (and report inexact if any rounding is needed).

The logic here is that, if rounding would produce a number within the exponent range anyway, then there is no overflow (even if the mathematical result exceeded the maximum representable finite number, as long as normal rounding would have brought it back in range).

The maximum finite value in IEEE-754 32-bit binary is 2<sup>128</sup>−2<sup>104</sup>. If the exponent range were unbounded, the next repesentable value would be 2<sup>128</sup>.

Let’s look at cases 2 and 3 first. In case 2, we add the maximum finite value to itself, so we have (2<sup>128</sup>−2<sup>104</sup>) + (2<sup>128</sup>−2<sup>104</sup>). Mathematically, this is 2<sup>129</sup>−2<sup>105</sup>. If the exponent range were unbounded, this would be representable, so no rounding would be necessary; it would be the result. Then that number has an exponent beyond the actual exponent range, so infinity is produced instead.

In case 3, we multiply the maximum finite value by 1.1 (which must actually be a value near 1.1, since 1.1 itself is not representable). So we have about (2<sup>128</sup>−2<sup>104</sup>) • 1.1. The real-number result would be over 2<sup>128</sup>, so, if the exponent range were unbounded, the floating-point result would be over 2<sup>128</sup>. That number has an exponent beyond the actual exponent range, so infinity is produced instead.

Now return to case 1. We add 10,000 to the maximum finite value, so we have 10,000 + (2<sup>128</sup>−2<sup>104</sup>), or 2<sup>128</sup>−2<sup>104</sup>+10,000. The midpoint between the maximum finite value (2<sup>128</sup>−2<sup>104</sup>) and the next value that would be representable with an unbounded exponent range (2<sup>128</sup>) is 2<sup>128</sup>−2<sup>105</sup>. Our real-number result, 2<sup>128</sup>−2<sup>104</sup>+10,000, is less than that midpoint. So, when using round-to-nearest-ties-to-even, we would round that result down to 2<sup>128</sup>−2<sup>104</sup>. That number is within the actual exponent range (its exponent is 127—we have just expressed it as 2<sup>128</sup> minus a bit instead of 2<sup>127</sup> plus a lot). So it is the result.

Thus 10,000 plus the maximum finite value produces the maximum finite value. It only went over the maximum finite value “a little bit” and was rounded down. The other operations went over the maximum finite value a lot and were rounded up.